# Add shared sqs queue to amazon console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have access to the queue which was shared for me from another account. I can working with it from AWS CLI or from my code, but can I see it in my aws console on the web site ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot see the other queue in the AWS Management Console.

The AWS Management Console only shows you resources which are in your own AWS account.

Since the SQS queue is in a different AWS account, you will not be able to see the queue in the AWS Management Console website. You can only access the SQS queue using the SDKs and AWS CLI.

Note: There are some exceptions to this rule, but SQS queues is not one of these exceptions.